Check which parts have been removed from the ".git" directory
I ran the command rm -rf ./.git in the terminal, but I send KILLSIG (with C-c from the keyboard) before the complete removal. Currently, the git history is not cleared and is there, but it logs some of the deleted stuff. How to check which parts are deleted?
NOTE: there is no remote repository.

Do you not have your changes pushed to a remote repository (gitty, gitlab, github. etc)? If you do, it's easier to just re-clone your directory.

There are a number of existing questions about fixing corrupted .git directories. I haven't gone through to find which are most likely to be useful, but you can search for yourself here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+corrupted

@blackbrandt exactly no any remote repository pushed. there is only local repository.
